# display flot pie chart dynamically when user clicks on div using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flot

[have a look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtBMS.png)

I  have 3 flot graphs and when user clicks on these graph I should display same graph on another div.whenever user clicks any of these graphs ,that graph should get displayed on  4th graph,it should change dynamically without reloading page.Graphs were drawn using jquery.

```
    |graph1| |graph2| |graph3|
            |graph4|
```

How to implement this using ajax and jquery?

pie.js

```
var piedata1 = [
    { label: "A", data: [[1,val['a1']]], color: '#D9534F'},
    { label: "B", data: [[1,val['a2']]], color: '#1CAF9A'},
    { label: "C", data: [[1,val['a3']]], color: '#F0AD4E'},
 ]; 
var piedata2 = [
    { label: "A", data: [[1,val['a1']]], color: '#D9534F'},
    { label: "B", data: [[1,val['a2']]], color: '#1CAF9A'},
    { label: "C", data: [[1,val['a3']]], color: '#F0AD4E'},
 ];  
var piedata3 = [
    { label: "A", data: [[1,val['a1']]], color: '#D9534F'},
    { label: "B", data: [[1,val['a2']]], color: '#1CAF9A'},
    { label: "C", data: [[1,val['a3']]], color: '#F0AD4E'},
 ];

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

"use strict"; 
jQuery.plot('#piechart1', piedata1, {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true,
            radius: 1,
            label: {
                show: false,
                radius: 2/3,
                formatter: labelFormatter1,
                threshold: 0.1
            }
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    },
    legend: {
    show: false
   },
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
    content: "%p.0%, %s", // show percentages, rounding to 2 decimal places
    shifts: {
      x: 20,
      y: 0
    },
    defaultTheme: false
  }
}); 
function labelFormatter1(label, series) {
    return "<div style='font-size:6pt; text-align:center; padding:2px; color:white;'>" + label + "<br/>" + Math.round(series.percent) + "%</div>";
}
jQuery.plot('#piechart2', piedata2, {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true,
            radius: 1,
            label: {
                show: false,
                radius: 2/3,
                formatter: labelFormatter2,
                threshold: 0.1
            }
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    },
    legend: {
    show: false
   },
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
    content: "%p.0%, %s", // show percentages, rounding to 2 decimal places
    shifts: {
      x: 20,
      y: 0
    },
    defaultTheme: false
  }
}); 
function labelFormatter2(label, series) {
    return "<div style='font-size:6pt; text-align:center; padding:2px; color:white;'>" + label + "<br/>" + Math.round(series.percent) + "%</div>";
}
jQuery.plot('#piechart3', piedata3, {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true,
            radius: 1,
            label: {
                show: false,
                radius: 2/3,
                formatter: labelFormatter3,
                threshold: 0.1
            }
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    },
    legend: {
    show: false
   },
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
    content: "%p.0%, %s", // show percentages, rounding to 2 decimal places
    shifts: {
      x: 20,
      y: 0
    },
    defaultTheme: false
  }
}); 
function labelFormatter3(label, series) {
    return "<div style='font-size:6pt; text-align:center; padding:2px; color:white;'>" + label + "<br/>" + Math.round(series.percent) + "%</div>";
}
});
```

how to solve this using ajax and jquery??